# Ionic 'path' option schema.json

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, macos-monterey

I'm working on an application in ionic/angular, I have updated my operating system to MacOs Monterrey and I have also updated the xCode.

Now when I creating new pages it gives me the following alert:

```
The 'path' option in '/../../node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit/page/schema.json' is using deprecated behaviour. 'workingDirectory' smart default provider should be used instead.
```

So far the pages are created and working fine, but I haven't been able to find any documentation about this problem.

Please, if someone can help me with information

regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the issue is that the schematic is not providing a default behaviour for the path, which is required, that causes the warning to appear.

(you can see the anuglar-cli code presenting the warning [link to github angular-cli](https://github.com/alan-agius4/angular-cli/blob/82ec1af4e1e34fe5b18db328b4bce6405a03c7b8/packages/angular/cli/src/command-builder/schematics-command-module.ts#L181-L187))

Basically the issue is that the schematic is missing some stuff, specifically here: [link to github ionic-team/angular-toolkit](https://github.com/ionic-team/angular-toolkit/blob/8ff0a235e0f64b1afcab06ee1958ff6e6d474288/packages/schematics/page/schema.json#L7-L11)

The path should include, (but it doesn't) the following property:

```json
"$default": {
 "$source": "workingDirectory"
}
```

That being said this is not an issue with your application, you probably just updated the angular-cli version and this issue started to show up, I would currently ignore it hoping that the ionic team adds that missing property soon, anyways this should not cause you any issue at the moment.

If you want I would suggest even maybe opening an issue and/or PR in the repo to speed things up if you feel like it :)

Comment: I've opened the issue in the repo :) https://github.com/ionic-team/angular-toolkit/issues/473 , I'd have a crack on fixing it too, but I am not really an ionic user so I'd need to look into how to run iconic and all that stuff, so I guess I'll just leave it for someone else to add that field :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try updating the

```
npm install @ionic/angular-toolkit@latest
```

As shown in their blog: https://ionic.io/blog/updates-to-ionic-angular-toolkit